# Find highest (max) date query, and then find highest value from results of previous query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is a table called `packages`:

```
id  packages_sent    date         sent_order
1 | 10             | 2017-02-11 | 1
2 | 25             | 2017-03-15 | 1
3 | 5              | 2017-04-08 | 1
4 | 20             | 2017-05-21 | 1
5 | 25             | 2017-05-21 | 2
6 | 5              | 2017-06-19 | 1
```

This table shows the number of packages sent on a given date; if there were multiple packages sent on the same date (as is the case with rows 4 and 5), then the `sent_order` keeps track of the order in which they were sent.

I am trying to make a query that will return `sum(packages_sent)` given the following conditions: first, return the row with the `max(date)` (given some date provided), and second, if there are multiple rows with the same `max(date)`, return the row with the `max(send_order)` (the highest `send_order` value).

Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT sum(packages_sent)
FROM packages 
WHERE date IN
    (SELECT max(date)
    FROM packages
    WHERE date <= '2017-05-29');
```

This query correctly finds the max date, which is `2017-05-21`, but then for the `sum` it returns `45` because it is adding rows `4` and `5` together.

I want the query to return the `max(date)`, and if there are multiple rows with the same `max(date)`, *then* return the row with the `max(sent_order)`. Using the example above with the date `2017-05-29`, it should only return `25`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where a `sum()` comes into play.  You seem to only want the last row:

```
select p.*
from packages p
order by date desc, sendorder desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you data is truly ordered ascending as you show it then it's easier to use the surrogate key ID field.

```
SELECT packages_sent
 FROM packages 
WHERE ID = 
  (SELECT max(ID)
    FROM packages
    WHERE date <= '2017-05-29');
```

Since the ID is always increasing with date and sent order finding the max of it also finds the max of the other two in one step.